# X:Bind datatemplate to event

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp, datatemplate, windows-10-universal

I'm tryin to call a method in my model class, from my datatemplate but doesn't seem to compile. Gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

On pointerPressed I want to call method "Poke" using X:bind in my lvitem call.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind m_ViewModel.ListItems}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:lvitem">
                <TextBlock PointerPressed="{x:Bind Poke , Mode=OneWay }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind m_ViewModel._Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

MyViewModel

```
Imports Windows.UI
Namespace MyViewModel
Public Class MyViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Name As String

    Private List_Items As New ObservableCollection(Of lvitem)

    Public Property _Name As String
        Get
            Return Name

        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Name = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Cater"
        Dim lvi As New lvitem
        Dim lvi2 As New lvitem
        List_Items.Add(lvi)
        List_Items.Add(lvi2)
    End Sub

    Public Property ListItems As ObservableCollection(Of lvitem)
        Get
            Return List_Items
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of lvitem))
            List_Items = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub ClickMe()
        _Name = "Clicked"

    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

CodeBehind

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page
Public Property ViewModel() As MyViewModel.MyViewModel
    Get
        Return m_ViewModel
    End Get
    Set
        m_ViewModel = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ViewModel As MyViewModel.MyViewModel
Public Sub New()

    Me.InitializeComponent()

    ViewModel = New MyViewModel.MyViewModel
End Sub

Private Sub Rectangle_PointerPressed(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBlock_PointerPressed(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)

End Sub
End Class
```

Lvitem Class - Model

```
Public Class lvitem
Public Sub New()

End Sub
Public Sub Poke(sender As Object, e As Object)
    Dim meint As Integer
    meint = 3
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

> Gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Yes, we have found some issues for x:bind with x:DataType in DataTemplate.

Here are some points we need to take care for now:

1. Ensure having a `Panel` to contain elements in the `DataTemplate`
2. For `TextBlock` control, if we need to make the event x:bind binding works, the `Text` property must be set x:bind binding.

I simplify your repro demo and standardize some naming issues:

**lvitem.vb:**

```
Public Class lvitem
    Public Sub Poke(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs)
        Dim meint As Integer
        meint = 3
    End Sub

    Private _Name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**MyViewModel.vb:**

```
Imports Windows.UI

Namespace MyViewModel
  Public Class MyViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private _Name As String

    Public List_Items As New ObservableCollection(Of lvitem)

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name

        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Name = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Cater"
        Dim lvi As New lvitem With {.Name = "Item1"}
        Dim lvi2 As New lvitem With {.Name = "Item2"}
        List_Items.Add(lvi)
        List_Items.Add(lvi2)
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

**View:**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Margin="0,100,0,0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind m_ViewModel.List_Items}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:lvitem">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock PointerPressed="{x:Bind Poke, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,100,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind m_ViewModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Please also note that **the PointerPressed event won't be triggered**, the reason is in here: [Can't fire PointerPressed event from a Listbox in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469908/cant-fire-pointerpressed-event-from-a-listbox-in-winrt)